# Typescript dependent nested object properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible to make few nested object properties depend on each other

Something like this:

```
type func = (props: any) => ...
type Obj = {
   [key: string]: {
      f: func, args: PARAMETERS OF "f", 
      f1: func, args1: PARAMETERS OF "f1" 
      ...
   }
}
const demo: Obj = {
   // here the type of "args" should be {name: string, age: number}
   key1: {f: (props: {name: string, age: number}) => ..., args: HERE SHOULD BE TYPED},  

   // here the type of "args" should be {somethingRandom: number[]}
   key2: {f: (props: {somethingRandom: number[]}) => ..., args: HERE SHOULD BE TYPED},

   ... more properties
}
```

Comment: There is no *specific* `Obj` type in TypeScript that works this way; you can make a generic type and associated helper function to get this effect, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAJoPW). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This may do the trick. Can you explain this a bit pls. How "K in keyof T" refers to 'key1' | 'key2' and at the same time to the arguments of the "f" as T[K]? How this can be used if I had few generic properties instead of 1, like f1, f2, f3 ...?

Comment: I think you might be talking about *inference from homomorphic mapped types*.  A homomorphic mapped type is of the form `type F<T> = {[K in keyof T]: ⋯T[K]⋯}`, and the compiler is often able to infer `T` from a value of type `F<T>`.  (This used to be documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) but the new handbook doesn't seem to contain this information, or at least not that I can find).

Comment: Your question "how can this be used if I had few generic properties instead of 1, like f1, f2, f3..." seems to be widening the scope of your question.  If you have to do that, I'd probably need to change my approach, since such inference from mapped types can break down in more complicated scenarios.  Hopefully you're not really going to expand the scope of the question, but if you are, please [edit] the question to do so explicitly and show example code that needs it.

Comment: ... How would you like to proceed here? Should I write up the answer explaining my original link? Or wait for an [edit] that expands the question scope?

Comment: What does `...` mean in your question?  Is it supposed to accept any properties the user wants?  Or is it some hardcoded list?  And your example is invalid; `args` cannot be in the object twice.

Comment: "..." means "and so on", the number does not matter, f and args, f1 and args1, f2 and args2, fN and argsN. I edited the "args"

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w25XrW) work for you?  I'm still confused when you say the number "does not matter".  *Who* chooses that number?

Comment: It is a test case. The names don't matter. What I wanted to achieve from beginning was: Get the type of specific nested property, so I can use it to get its prop types, return values, or maybe some properties from first class object. Like accessing value of "f" inside "key1". const addTypes = <F extends func = func>(p: {f: F, args: (Parameters<F>)[0], returnType: ReturnType<F>}) => p, this way I can add types to everything that I want that depends on F, but I dont know how to make something like this for nested objects. {key1: addTypes(...), key2: addTypes(...)} will work, but I do not like it

Comment: You say they don't matter but I don't know how to generalize on that.  If the names aren't always `f` and `args` followed by some related suffix, how am I supposed to match up the right function with the right arguments? The names have to matter *somehow*. I don't have the ability to generalize from `...`.  Please just either give me a hardcoded list and *you* can generalize based on my code, or tell me that the names literally don't matter and then describe in detail how I'm supposed to match things up.  And, uh, did [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w25XrW) do the job or not?

Comment: I will accept it if you put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript that corresponds exactly to the values you want `Obj` to accept.  Instead, you could write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `Obj<T>` which acts as a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `T` such that if `T extends Obj<T>` then `T` is acceptable, and otherwise `Obj<T>` will be some "correct" version of `T`.  Then you could write a generic helper function `asObj(obj)` which returns its input, but will warn you if `obj` isn't a valid `Obj<T>` for some `T`.

That is, we want to write

```
type Obj<T> = ⋯;
```

and then something like

```
const asObj = <T extends Obj<T>>(obj: T) => obj;
```

but more likely

```
const asObj = <T,>(obj: T & Obj<T>): T => obj;
```

since the former version might not work (possible circular constraint) and might produce an unfortunate output type (might be `Obj<{⋯}>` instead of `{⋯}`, which could be different enough to matter).

So now the question is how to define `Obj<T>`.

---

It could look like this.  Since each property of your intended `Obj` type is tested independently, we can make it a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over some other type function that checks a single property:

```
type Obj<T> = { [K in keyof T]: F<T[K]> }
```

So now we need to define `F<>`:

```
type F<T> =
   { [S in Suffixes as `f${S}`]: 
       (props: never) => void 
   } & { [S in Suffixes as `args${S}`]: 
       T extends Record<`f${S}`, (props: infer P) => void> ? P : never 
   }

type Suffixes = "" | "1" | "2" // <-- set this to however many you need
```

So `F<T>` should verify that `T` is a valid `Obj` property.  What we do is make sure that it has all the `f` and `args` members that we expect (you can choose how many by modifying the `Suffixes` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)).  We need `f`, `f1`, `f2`, etc., to be functions of one argument (a function `(props: never) => void` will accept any one-arg function), and we need `args`, `args1`, `args2`, etc., to be the valid argument type for the corresponding `f` function.  These are represented with [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) and [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types); essentially for each `argXX` it looks up the `fXX` function in `T` and infers its argument type.

---

Okay so let's test it out:

```
const asObj = <T,>(obj: T & Obj<T>): T => obj;

const demo = asObj({
   key1: {
      f: (props: { name: string, age: number }) => { }, args: { age: 3, name: "" },
      f1: (props: { name: 2 }) => { }, args1: { name: 2 },
      f2: (props: unknown) => { }, args2: 2
   },
   key2: {
      f: (props: { x: boolean }) => { }, args: { x: true },
      f1: (props: { z: Date }) => { }, args1: { z: new Date() },
      f2: (props: number) => { }, args2: "oops" // error
   },
});

demo.key1.f(demo.key1.args); // okay
demo.key2.f1(demo.key2.args1); // okay
```

Looks good. The compiler enforces that each `arg` corresponds to each `f`, and you get an error if you make a mistake.  And the type of `demo` is strong enough that it remembers which arguments go to which methods.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgMwQSwB4QM5QLxQER5QA++AjISXgEyED0tUAPALTNQYTBTAAWyWwAPZQeggO4QAbhABOUALYBDAHYgoIQXCjKIEACYAoA6EhQA8gCMAVowAqAPhxQA3lADaAaSjJlUANYQGghQtgC6AFxQAGJ2nqGOAL7G4NAxDjgGUFmubjDevvBIaJhQilgABggAJM4wCeURUAAUYDKCYBiROtIyAJQ4jpKCyHpQCVAAZJnZ7nk+sIgo6FhlUOWKMgDmGDV1DZG2UBCowBDKelgAShAAxoIyeoyVu-UANM2t7Z35CLJQAAr9bCDYZ6RwAfgBUC6Uj+SSM9Cgd2UGC4ZUsVicdiOJzOF3M1js9nsTUE1gOQMcZKsAG4DMjUaUMBisbZXiTqQdJgSbA5elzgVBqXT6YIUVw9BB5MJcOjrE1nNN-IFSJFFVkNVAEJEWm0OmrtIp5BBIqiZD5Nu9FJsTdo4PILHDKS4xlatt9XNbbQBmd7KI22giupUahCqj56j2G42RKhjZ2uBJu7bh1z+mNQONJkNZBBUHWffVQODKPzKcTKBOu0ru-OZpXZjUBEB19WarUFyMG1CRCyCQQAGwgKnjAxdSZr227kWAMjg0Eb7bDna+BoAXpEACKKU6jwWJ5MYVNQDfaCBiKDb05NfqLzV5ldF5T2x19McHycYOt4fsdOgMWQ2hkBtXgMBJehFSVpQAOmbUhoIQJooMEWCVWgjZtggqBEUEPxFBAAxkNQlsENIJCpRQ5sqHQ91SCwnC8IIoA)